# Overriding Tab press in widget with QWidget::event

Tags: c++, qt5

I'm trying to override the tab/backtab press in a QWidget consisting of a qlineedit and a qtablewidget so that the row selection in qtablewidget increases while the qlineedit keeps keyboard focus, though I've ran into a  weird problem.

Regular Tab press works as expected, Backtab however, jumps back 2 rows instead of one without keypressEvent getting called more than one. If the selected row is 1, it goes to the previous row(0) but pressing Tab after that results in tab jumping 2 rows, and any more tab pushes correctly increases row select by 1 while backtab continues to jump 2 rows.

```cpp
bool FloatingCommandBar::event(QEvent *event) {
    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyRelease) {
        QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);

        if (keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Tab) {
            keyPressEvent(keyEvent);
            qDebug() << "event tab";
            return true;
        } else if (keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Backtab) {
            keyPressEvent(keyEvent);
            qDebug() << "event backtab";
            return true;
        }
    } else if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
        QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);

        if (keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Tab) {
            //keyPressEvent(keyEvent);
            return false;
        } else if (keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Backtab) {
            //keyPressEvent(keyEvent);
            return false;
        }
    }

    return QWidget::event(event);
}

void FloatingCommandBar::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event) {
    if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Tab) {
        if (m_suggestwidget->currentRow() < m_suggestwidget->rowCount()) {
            m_suggestwidget->selectRow(m_suggestwidget->currentRow()+1);
            qDebug() << "keypressEvent tab";
            return;
        }
    } else if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Backtab) {
        if (m_suggestwidget->currentRow() > 0) {
            m_suggestwidget->selectRow(m_suggestwidget->currentRow()-1);
            qDebug() << "keypressEvent backtab";
            return;
        }
    }

    QWidget::keyPressEvent(event);
    emit onKeyPress(event);
}
```

Anyone happen to know how to fix this or a better solution for keeping keyboard focus on qlineedit while qtablewidget shows a list suggestions and tab/backtab increases/decreases row selection instead of changing child widget focus?

Comment: You probably want to accept the event so it doesn't get populated further (event->accept())

Comment: Tried it but it didn't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected by moving the code to the qlineedit and setting qtablewidget focuspolicy to NoFocus.